# Android substring by characher

Tags: java, android, string, substring

I want to remove the [ ] from my string

String food - returns

```
[ apple, banana, orange ]
```

I just want to have as : apple, banana, orange

thanks guys

Comment: You mean you want to remove the `[` and `]` ?

Comment: yes. thats is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write

```
food.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")
```

which returns a new `String`, with all `[` and `]` characters removed.

Answer (score 5):

Yo can replace the characters as-

```
    String fruits = "[ apple, banana, orange ]";
    fruits = fruits.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the [] will always be at the beginning and end of a string, such as this case, and you want to remove them a simple
   `//substring to remove []s and trim to remove whitespace`
   `string_name.substring(1,string_name.lenght()-1).trim();`
will do the trick, without needing to know regex.